# My class selector isn't working for parsley-error

Tags: parsley.js

I'm trying to act on fields which have the parsley-error class, unfortunately the following code isn't working.

```
$('.parsley-error').on('focusin', function() {
    console.log('yep');
});
```

if I change it to this:

```
$('input').on('focusin', function() {
    console.log('yep');
});
```

then that works, so I know the code is being run ... just that the selector isn't working.  Any help is, of course, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `$('.parsley-error').on...`, your jQuery set is probably empty, as there aren't any errors yet. So your code does nothing.

You probably want to use delegated events `$(document).on('focusin', '.parsley-error', ...)` instead. Or use the parsley events to do stuff when there's an error.

Comment: Thank you! $(document).on('focusin', '.parsley-error', ...) solved it.  Still don't understand what the issue was, but appreciate getting a solution.